# Disable relocations when linking with LLD

Tags: llvm, relocation, lld

Is there an option for `lld` that will tell it not to perform relocations. I don't want PIC code, I just want relocations not to be performed. (Yes I know this will result in an executable that doesn't work.)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out to be an easy and fairly obvious solution - just pass `-r` or `--relocatable`. Then it won't apply relocations but will store them in the output file instead.

Edit: Unfortunately this does not *quite* have the effect I want, because you can't use `--gc-sections` and `--relocatable` at the same time.

Comment: So I guess you want to, to put it in other words, discard the relocations?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I ended up having to patch LLVM locally and add an `--ignore-relocations` flag which does exactly that.